# How could I split a string in the format 'htmlElement#idName.className.anotherClassName'?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like that `header#top.header.header--show-offset` and I'm struggling to know how could I split it into something like `[ 'header', '#top', '.header', '.header--show-offset' ]`

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex:

```js
let str ="header#top.header.header--show-offset";

// Keep the delimiter
let res = str.split(/(?=[#.])/gi);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This almost works. He wants to keep the `#` or `.` character in the array after the split. So you need to split on a lookahead - `str.split(/(?=[#.])/g);`

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in two steps:

1. Replace id and class symbols with a comma and then the symbol
2. Split the resulting string by comma

```js
var selectorString = "header#top.header.header--show-offset";
selectorString = selectorString.replace(/#/g, ",#")
selectorString = selectorString.replace(/\./g, ",.");
var selectorList = selectorString.split(",");
console.log(selectorList);
```